# Lost Pokemon Go data

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon is pretty fun, been playing since its release, yet it's still very glitchy.
I started my brother on it yesterday and he got to level 5 with some nice Pokemon. 
Today I decided to log him on another device and when the game loaded, it started on the screen when Professor Willow introduces you into the world of Pokemon. The account was still logged in on the first device we used. I tried making a new profile using the same username used on his first account and it said "Username unavailable" or whatever it says. So the his first account still exists but I can't access it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign out of your current account and login to the one your brother was playing on.

You can sign out by clicking the Pokeball on the bottom center of the screen, clicking the Settings button on the top right, and then scrolling to the bottom and selecting the sign out option.